# Why does this code give undefined error? firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this code for retriving document list from firebase collections and processing it to a new list.

But it gives error message:

> Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore value. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "myPick"). If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

What seems to be the problem?

ps - when I test-called 'currentFoodPickList[0].foodCondition', it gave a correct value. so it seems something went wrong while processing 'finalFoodList'

ps2 - new error message after using ignoreUndefinedProperties setting:

> Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore value. "undefined" values are only ignored in object properties.

ps3 - If someone could suggest any other way of processing 'currentFoodPickList' => 'finalFoodList', I'd really appreciate it.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })


exports.onFoodDocumentUpdate = functions.firestore.document('foods/{foodID}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

    const foodDataAfter = change.after.data();
    const currentFoodID = context.params.foodID

    const currentFoodPickList = await admin.firestore().collection('foods').doc(currentFoodID).collection('foodPickRecord').get().then(function(docs) {
        let res = []
        docs.forEach(doc => res.push(doc.data()));
        return res;
    })


    const finalFoodList = [];

    for (var f in currentFoodPickList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < f.amount; i++) {
            finalFoodList.push(f.foodCondition)
        }
    }

    return admin.firestore().collection('foods').doc(currentfoodID).update({
        myPick: finalFoodList[0]
    });
});
```

Comment: Firebase doesn't accept `undefined` values. In your `finalFoodList` check if you have an undefined value. If so, use `ignoreUndefinedProperties` setting as suggested by the error msg.

Comment: As @Phiter well mentioned, the solution and cause for your issue it's clear via the stack trace. Please, give it a try using the `ignoreUndefinedProperties` setting, to confirm that this fixes the issue.

Comment: @gso_gabriel After using ignoreUndefinedProperties as you adviced, I got this error message => Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore value. "undefined" values are only ignored in object properties.

Comment: Hi @AndyYoung thanks for returning and confirming the usage. This just confirms that in your code, there is an `undefined` value in your list. I would recommend you to be printing the results from each value in your list, every time the `for` is occurring, to check when the undefined value is showing up.